# i would need a script to be executed but the page shouldn't be navigated

Tags: php, url

i use the below code to navigate to a specific site via php code.

```
 header('Location:www.google.com');
```

i would need a script to be executed but the page shouldn't be navigated. my requirement is - i would like to send message to a person using a link but no page should be navigated as it by the click of a button - execution of the link at server end.

can you please let me know how to do.

thanks,
Sam

Comment: Have you heard of `AJAX`. Check this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i need this to be executed at server end... as i need to fetch the members name from db and send message to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execute this code on a button click or a  tag click event.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sever url",
    data: { message: "hello" }
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "script executed successfully ");
    this.preventDefault(); // stops navigating from the page while <a> click or on submit click.
    });
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to be done at server end... (i'll have this tried as well)...

Comment: i know.. in the event of button click, via ajax i have the php script executed during when i pull out the member's phone number for message.. i would need to execute the url in batch so that the message is sent out.. thanks!

Comment: i did a echo or all these in php page and it executed :)

Comment: @SamuelMathews great :)