# execute link in background using PHP

Tags: php

Please read below my scenario..
I have been given a link.. On executing the link in web browser, message will be sent to the intended recipients .. But for my website I need the link to be executed in php as I would retrieve member name from db...
Steps....

```
      Retrieve name from db
      $URL = "ABC.com&msg=".$msg
      (Execute the link)
       /* do something 

 url = 'http://api.smsgatewayhub.com/smsapi/pushsms.aspx?user=stthomasmtc&pwd=429944&to=9176411081&sid=STMTSC&msg=Dear%20Sam,%20choir%20practice%20will%20be%20held%20in%20our%20Church%20on%20July%2031%20at%208:00%20pm.%20Thanks,%20St.%20Thomas%20MTC!&fl=0&gwid=2'
```

I am not sure how to execute a link without redirecting.. Hence cannot use header()
I tried using file_get_contents() but didn't work..

Can you please guide me.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CURL to hit the URL after fetching the details from database.
[PHP Manual Curl.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```
function get_http_request($uri, $time_out = 100, $headers = 0)
{
    $ch = curl_init(); // Initializing
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($uri)); // Set URI
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers); //Set Header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $time_out); // Time-out in seconds
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // Executing
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($httpCode != 200) {
        $result = ""; // Executing
    }
    curl_close($ch); // Closing the channel
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will chk n gt back to you.. :)

Comment: Does this curl work in XAMPP.. From local system... Or should I have it uploaded to server to execute the script..

Comment: yeah it works on Xampp. You just need to enable php curl extension in php.ini.

Comment: hi vivek.. 
being new to curl, can you please help me out.. 
i checked the php.ini file and its mentioned as 
     extension=php_curl.dll

and in the ode i have updated as below

    function get_http_request($uri, $time_out = 100, $headers = 0)
    {
    $uri='http://abc'; //my url
    $ch = curl_init(); // Initializing
     .....

and on executing i dont find the link being executed... can you please help me out.. thanks in advance!

Comment: hi,I beleive you have uncomment the line `extension=php_curl.dll` in php.ini. you can also run php function `phpinfo()` to check if curl is enabled on your server or not ?. If enable, then use the above function by passing valid URL($uri) as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Why not you are using AJAX, 
As well through the AJAX you can also execute external link by using http client and can get the data and send it back in UI side.
once you retrieve the data in JSON/XML format then render the same.

Comment: This would be two way round.. First an ajax to fetch name from db.. Then execute the link in JavaScript.. Then back to ajax for updating db tat the message was sent (as log).. If v could handle executing link in PHP things would b easier.. :(

Comment: Anyways.. How will we execute link in JavaScript without page redirection..?   Thanks!

Comment: Try this                                                        $.ajax({
    type:     "GET",
    url:      "https://http://freetexthost.com/r56ct5aw03", // <-- Here
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});

Comment: this isnt working :(
url i wanted to execute is 
//$url='http://api.smsgatewayhub.com/smsapi/pushsms.aspx?user=stthomasmtc&pwd=429944&to=9176411081&sid=STMTSC&msg=Dear Sam, choir practice will be held in our Church on July 31 at 8:00 pm. Thanks, St. Thomas MTC!&fl=0&gwid=2';

Comment: @SamuelMathews Your url is not readable, can you please edit your top post and provide the url at last so that I can try my best to provide you a working code or solution.

Comment: done.. thanks again!   (with the link, i send a msg to my own number)

Comment: prashanth... thanks, i was able to fix with the javascript code mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988531/i-would-need-a-script-to-be-executed-but-the-page-shouldnt-be-navigated/24989080?noredirect=1#comment38851145_24989080

Comment: and for the php page, i did a echo for each statement and thereby executed the ajax javasript and got my desired result :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you'd need the `http://` part for file_get_contents to work:

```
$URL = "http://example.com&msg=".$msg
$result = file_get_contents($URL);
```